# Read all nodes and child nodes recursively

Tags: c#, recursion

I have an object **Node** with **child** **Nodes**. 
I would like to read all the Nodes & child nodes and display them into an asp.net dropdown list control.

The node is of type :

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundataion.WorkItemTracking.Client.Node
```

The Class Node looks like this :

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Each Node has many child nodes & the child nodes have more child nodes and so on....

I have code written to fetch the node & first level of child node. 
I cannot think how I can recursively read all the nodes ??

```
Dictionary<string,string> ParentN = new Dictionary<string,string>();
Dictionary<string, string> childN = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (Node area in Proj.Nodes)
{
    ParentN.Add(area.Name, area.Path);
    Console.WriteLine(area.Path);

    foreach (Node item in area.ChildNodes)
    {
        childN.Add(item.Name, item.Path);
        Console.WriteLine(item.Path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a recursive function for that. Children can be parents too. If a child has no children beneath it, then we don't add it to the parents dict.

```
void GetNode(Node parent)
{
    if (parent.ChildNodes.Any())
    {
        ParentN.Add(parent.Name, parent.Path);
        foreach(child in parent.ChildNodes)
        {
            childN.Add(child.Name, child.Path);
            GetNode(child);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(parent.Name);
}
```

Comment: i cant use .Any() in parent.ChildNodes.Any().. It give me an error saying NodeCollection doesnt contain a definition for Any

Comment: @PowerCoder well, I don't know what type is your `Proj.Nodes`, it's just a check if there are any children.

Comment: for Any you'll need `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @PowerCoder of what type is your ChildNodes collection?

Comment: It is of type Microsoft.TeamFoundataion.WorkItemTracking.Client.Node

Comment: @PowerCoder the `ChildNodes` property has a `Node` type?

Comment: It has a property haschildnodes .. I am using it . instead of .Any(). Now I get a stack overflow exception while running through code..

Comment: @PowerCoder how many nodes/children do you have? Recursion is not a solution for very large collections

Comment: It has around 4-5 levels of child nodes.. but its not too large.. I think there is some problem with the algorithm.. i am trying to debug it....

Comment: Its going into an infinite loop .. You see .. After childN.Add(child.Name, child.Path); we call the GetNode(parent); The control goes to the parent. It reads the first child node and goes back to the parent . reads the first child again and goes back to the parent and so on.....

Comment: @PowerCoder I've edited the solution, a small type and nothing works :) That's what happens when you try to do something at midnight :)

Answer (score 2):

The class Node you posted does not contain child nodes. I'll assume you meant:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path {get; set;}
    IList<Node> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

You could do it as:

```
static class NodeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Node> ReadChildNodes(this Node node)
    {
        foreach(Node childNode in node.ChildNodes){
            if(childNode.ChildNodes != null && childNode.ChildNodes.Any()){
                foreach(Node grandChildren in childNode.ReadChildNodes())
                    yield return grandChildren;
            }

            yield return childNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Probably this code can be improved, but it works, I guess...